# How does one input positive and negative infinities into MIT Scheme?

Tags: mit-scheme

[Section 4.7.2 of the MIT/GNU Scheme Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Flonum-Operations.html#Flonum-Operations) states that

> The IEEE floating-point number specification supports three special ‘numbers’: positive infinity (`+inf`), negative infinity (`-inf`), and not-a-number (`NaN`).

These constants, in addition to being well-defined IEEE floating-point values, are also useful for range arithmetic.  However, I’m unable to use them in my programs:

```
1 ]=> +inf

;Unbound variable: +inf
```

Generating these values isn’t easy, either: expressions which seem like they ought to evaluate to floating-point infinities simply don’t:

```
1 ]=> (flo:/ 1. 0.)

;Floating-point division by zero
```

How can I input or generate infinite floating-point constants in MIT Scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tests/runtime/test-arith.scm](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mit-scheme.git/tree/tests/runtime/test-arith.scm?id=release-9.2.0#n31) suggests using `flo:with-exceptions-untrapped`:

```
;;; XXX The nonsense about IDENTITY-PROCEDURE here serves to fake
;;; out bogus constant-folding which needs to be fixed in SF (and
;;; probably LIAR too).

(define (zero)
  (identity-procedure 0.))

(define (nan)
  (flo:with-exceptions-untrapped (flo:exception:invalid-operation)
    (lambda ()
      (flo:/ (zero) (zero)))))

(define (inf+)
  (flo:with-exceptions-untrapped (flo:exception:divide-by-zero)
    (lambda ()
      (flo:/ +1. (zero)))))

(define (inf-)
  (flo:with-exceptions-untrapped (flo:exception:divide-by-zero)
    (lambda ()
      (flo:/ -1. (zero)))))
```

The results display as `#[NaN]`, `#[+inf]`, `#[-inf]` but cannot be input that way.